# Android studio throwing error Invalid packageName while trying to run the app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am having one android project with diffrent build flavours like "Debug,release,SIT,UAT,...".Based on the build variant the package name is changing(Dynamic).Like if i select SIT the package name would be com.abc.xyz.SIT and if i will select UAT it will be like com.abc.xyz.UAT.(Suffix).

This is working very fine previously,Suddenly it stopped working with an error as below

`2022-12-30 15:46:32.988   562-4108  ActivityManager         system_process                       W  Invalid packageName: com.mbb.mketrade.sit 2022-12-30 16:24:03.265   562-932   ActivityManager         system_process                       W  Invalid packageName: com.mbb.mketrade.sit`

Surprisingly...I am able to generate the signed bundle and apk from the same source code from the android studio and can run the exported apk/bundle to the emulator but when i am trying to run it manually by hitting "Run" option it always give me error "INVALID PACKAGE NAME".

I have tried couple of steps as google suggested as below without luck.
1)Checked my manifest and build.gradle file where i have. not changed anything.
2)Tried creating a new emulator
3)tried invalidating caches and restarted the emulator.

I am still looking for any solution.Can anyone please help me on this.

I have attached my run configurations.
[Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IPgD.png)

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with your Android Studio run configuration, not the app itself.

Comment: @laalto- Ok let me share my Run configuration as a screenshot.May help me.

Comment: I have added my Run configutation with the question @laalto..Can u help me by checking this please?